# May I use 2 sig in one module?

Tags: ocaml

I want to create database and table datatypes in OCaml. May I use 2 `sig` keywords in 1 module? Could you give an example of how to write a signature and how to implement it?

Comment: What happen when you try it? Please post the code of your attempt and what the compiler says about it.

Comment: I don't know I am very new to ocaml and havn't implemented the rest of the code to know for sure it if works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to have a module that satisfies 2 module types, yes, you can.

```
module type ADDITIVE = sig
    type t
    val add : t -> t -> t
end

module type MULTIPLICATIVE = sig
    type t
    val multiply : t -> t -> t
end

module Number : sig
    include ADDITIVE
    include MULTIPLICATIVE with type t := t
end = struct
    type t = int
    let add x y = x + y
    let multiply x y = x + y
end
```

We say the signature of module `Number` is the inclusion of module type `ADDITIVE` (that opens `t` in that context) and `MULTIPLICATIVE` with the same type in `t` of the `t` from `ADDITIVE`, so we can implement the module according to the signature.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo for deep answer!!